# How to easily encrypt a directory on backup USB on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, encryption

I have an unencrypted USB stick that I don't want encrypted.

However, I want to save some data in a folder encrypted on that particular USB, in a way that will allow me to decrypt it again on another computer if I know the passphrase. Just that one folder.

What I would also like is that for decrypting, I wouldn't need admin priviledges.

All the solutions I found were really complicated and dealt with use cases I don't really need (for example, encrypting the whole filesystem or somehow tying the passphrase with the user).

I have Ubuntu Linux. I tried using Cryptfs but it is just giving me errors that I can't decypher.

(This will very possible be a duplicate and I will be very gladly shown at least some answer)

Comment: This is what a TrueCrypt container is for.

Answer (score 0):

What I found:

```
 sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/username/diskname/folder /media/username/diskname/folder
```

puts the folder into "decrypted mode"

```
 sudo umount ecryptfs /media/username/diskname/folder
```

puts the folder into "encrypted mode"

I still need to be sudoer for that though.